# Open source feed sharing app: RSS to Twitter/Facebook

Tags: web-apps, open-source, web-development, rss

Is there any open source web app that I could download and use, that is similar to:

- http://twitterfeed.com
- https://dlvr.it

It doesn't have to have all the feature, it's okay if it has the basic stuff, I could edit the source code.

- Ability to manage feeds: grab a url, parse feed, share it on Facebook and Twitter.
- Multiple users, multiple feeds per user.
- Must run on Linux
- I need RSS support, if it supports Atom too, it's great
- Tracking traffic is a plus
- If it's written with Django it's a plus, not a must
- I don't care if the application is lightweight or not, I could buy more powerful servers.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations Stack Exchange! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore no everything is there per rules:
**What kind of application are you looking for?** I already said, **What operating system do you want the application to run on?** obviously linux. I don't care about the hardware, I can buy bigger servers if needed, **What features must the application have?** I already said ability to manage feed, like fetch and share on social medias and manage users, and I gave 2 examples in case my explanation wasn't enough, tell me what information do you want exactly and I will edit my question, my goal and requirements are listed above

Comment: Your question still does not fit within our minimum quality guidelines. I recommend you read both the question and the corresponding answer in their entirety and try looking at a few example questions here on SR.

Comment: What kind of feeds do you need to support? Atom? RSS?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Rss, but it if it's support both, it's great

Comment: RSSGraffiti was discontinued, situation is getting worse. :/